# How can fix the position of Edit box with bounding box in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am dealing with face detection and recognition and I am getting bounding box around the face. now I want to add Edit box at the bottom of bounding box displaying name.
I am using this command

```
set(handles.result,'String','Unknown Person','units','pix','position',[bbox(1) bbox(2) 200     30]);
```

but it is not as I desire and also it is not fixed . in each frame it moves separately from the bounding box. Please guide me in this regard.
Thnaks

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can better understand your question.

Comment: Do you add the edit boxes programmatically? How do you know how many of them should appear on the interface? ...or is it always just 1?

A screenshot of your figure could also help greatly.

Comment: Can't you use a text annotation instead of an edit text box?

Comment: Try using different units, maybe normalized?